# ValueError - DataFunction

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I get this error when I run my code:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Code:

```py
def calculate_pay(vehicle,hours):
    if vehicle == 'Bike':
        pay = 9.99
    elif vehicle == 'Walking & Public Transportation':
        pay = 9.99
    else:
        pay = 14.00
    return hours*pay
```

Here's the example of the excel data: [image: Screenshot of Excel spreadsheet]

I'd like the output to print:

```
ID - Printed per row of data 

Vehicle Type used

Hours 

Total Pay calculated from the function
```

This will be exported back into Excel.

Comment: Please show the definition of `vehicle` and how you call `calculate_pay`...

Comment: What do you mean by exported back to excel ? Also please share the full code and not just the function.

You need to print other details which are not present in the function. It would be easier for us to understand. Sample output would also help.

Comment: You need to use `df['Vehicle', 'Hours'].apply(calculate_pay)`

Comment: @user17242583 vehicle would be referring to the excel column in the data sheet. 

I call calculate_pay with this: 
df["Total Pay"] = df.apply(calculate_pay(df["Vehicle"], df["Hours"])) 

I'm not sure if any of this is correct as I'm new so bear with me, sorry.

Comment: You have the idea, you're just using Pandas a little wrong. I'll write an answer to help you.

Comment: @Barmar When I enter that line of code, it asks me to fill in calculate_pay with vehicle and hours. I want it to input the data from the excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
prices = {
    'Bike': 9.99,
    'Walking & Public Transportation': 9.99,
}
default_price = 14.00

df['TotalPay'] = df.apply(lambda x: prices[x.get('Vehicle', default_price)]*x['Hours'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Instead of having default price = 14.00, could I add it to the list of prices? 14.00 is the price of Cargo-bikes. How would this change the final line of code? Thanks for your help

Comment: The `default_price` is used if a row in the `Vehicle` column is not listed in the `prices` dict. Just something like `'Cargo-bike': 14.00,` or whatever will appear in the spreadsheet, to the dict.

Comment: I get KeyError: 'Cargo-bike' when I run the code

Comment: That shouldn't be. Did you add `'Cargo-bike': 14.00,` to the `prices` dict?

Comment: I've added Cargo-bikes into the list now. Will I still have to keep default_price in the code or can I remove now that I have Cargo-bike to prices? The code seems to be running fine now. Is there any way I can print it out showing each row including ID, vehicle, hours and then the total pay?

Comment: Sure, you can remove `default_price`, but if a value appears in the `Vehicle` column that isn't in the dict, you'll have an error and you'll need to add it to the dict. You'll also need to remove `default_price` from the `prices.get()` call.

Comment: I'm not sure why the dataframe is being printed - are you called df.head() or something?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Everything is working now :D

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to be of service.

Comment: Quick question - If there are multiple entries for 1 user ID, will this be merged into 1 row? I don't really need to know what vehicle types they're using, just that they're receiving the correct pay by vehicle type and total pay.

Comment: Nope. This code only modifies existing rows.